# how to call methods with multiple arguments

Tags: python

i am trying to learn python. in a method like average below how can call this method without supplying value for a means we only supply values for b.
How will we call such a method.

```
def average(a=5 , *b):
    sum=0
    count=0
    print(" b is {0}".format(b))
    for bb in b:
        sum += bb
        count+=1
    av=(sum+a)/(count+1)
    return av

print("average is {0}".format(average(3,5,7,8,9,2)))
```

Here it takes a=3 and the rest as b. How can we call this method without value for a at all.

Can we have the first value as nargs like . If yes how do we supply the value of b.

```
def average(*a,b)
```

Comment: so you want to call it without a and with b? why? but i think `average(b=(1,2,3))` should work...

Comment: _" in a method like this how can call this method without supplying value for a"_ - Do you want a default value for a?

Comment: hey, you want answer on `a=5, *b` or `*a, b`?

Comment: That is a *function* not a *method*

Comment: @M.Volf average(b=(1,2,3)) is not working.

Answer (score 3):

```
def average(*a, b):
    ...
```

Using the syntax above, you must include `b` by keyword-only:

```
average(1,2,3,b=4)
```

If you don't like that, then just unpack inside the function directly like shown below:

```
def average(*args):
    *a, b = args
    ...
```

You will need to add handling for the case where args is empty.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye:  Given that [Python 2.7 is nearing EOL in about 2 years...](https://pythonclock.org/) seems like a good time to migrate over.

Comment: what i have got from answers from all is if function is average(*a,b) then we need to specify average(1,2,3,b=4) and if we have average(a=5,*b) and we need to call without passing a then average(b=(2,3,4)). thanks

Comment: i am able to run average(1,2,3,b=4) but running average(b=(1,2,3)) is not working and generates an error TypeError: average() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'. Can anybody update

Comment: The first method shown in this answer already works with `average(b=(1,2,3))`.  The argument `a` will take the empty tuple here.

Comment: @wim but second one is not working i.e average(a=5,*b) is not working for average(b=(1,2,3))

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: @wim for the function average(a=5,*b) how can i call it without passing value for a at all. i make the call average(b=(1,2,3)) but compiler gives an error- unexpected argument b. hope this clears

Comment: Then put it the other way around and make `a` keyword-only: `def average(*b, a=5):`.  And you have to make a decision about if you want to pass all `b` in one collection, or pass them all separately (you can't do both).